# pg 9.4 vs 10 differences on order by random()

Tags: postgresql

Following query is not randomizing array in postgres 10. Is this expected behaviour?

```
select array(select generate_series(1,10) order by random());
```

v9.4.15

```
     array
------------------------
 {7,1,10,6,2,8,9,4,5,3}
```

v10.4

```
         array
------------------------
 {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
```

Comment: `select array(select * from generate_series(1,10) order by random());` is working as expected though, but wonder what happened in v10.

Comment: Please check execution plans between 9.4 and 9.6 https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=67e75818c8134b14ec2de971e56dcf91  9.6 behaves exactly like v10.4

Comment: @lad2025 tnx, is this covered somewhere in changelog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consequence of [commit 69f4b9c85f168ae006929eec44fc44d569e846b9](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=69f4b9c85f168ae006929eec44fc44d569e846b9) that changes how set-returning functions in the `SELECT` list are handled.

Tim's answer and your comment show how to deal with the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is the newer version of Postgres has an optimizer which is getting smarter, and is caching away the value of `random()` after a single call to that function.

One workaround is to force a new random value to be calculated for each record.  We can add a dummy `WHERE` clause to force this:

```
WITH cte AS (
    select generate_series(1,10) AS col
)

SELECT col
FROM cte
WHERE col IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY random();
```

### Demo

You may observe in the demo that the order is in fact random.  However, in the same demo if you run your orignal query the order won't be random.

**Edit:**

The reason why this tricks works is that the `WHERE` clause convinces the optimizer that you really care about the values being used in each record.  Therefore, it calls the function in `ORDER BY` once for each record rather than caching it.

Comment: `select * from generate_series(1,10) order by random()` is also randomizing, perhaps it turns off optimizer in such case.

Comment: @Сухой27 No it's not...at least [not in this demo](http://rextester.com/MOZO87757).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you're missing `.. * from ..`

Comment: @Caramiriel I remember why now.  It has to do with checking the value of each row in the `WHERE` clause, see my edit above.

Comment: It is not a question of the optimizer being smart; see my answer.